# Why is it that whenever I partition my sd card outside CWM it doesn't get recognized by my phone?

Tags: cyanogenmod, external-sd, partitions, ext4, sd-ext

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace, running on its official CM7 ROM. I have an 8gb sd card and I just want to make a clean install of everthing starting with the sd card's partition.

I've had sd-ext partition troubles when I partitioned my sd card using CWM, so I went and did it using GParted. Currently it has:

1. 6+ Gb FAT32 primary partition
2. 1 Gb EXT4 logical partition

It gets recognized by my laptop, no problem. But my phone won't even detect it. Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating the sd-ext partition as another primary partition. Works fine now. I hope this helps somebody.